# Destinator navigation program and sms issue

Tags: android, navigation, sms

new to android and lovin it so far. I have this issue which i need to solve and it may need a simple solution.

Intrinsic Destinator software has a feature of receiving an sms with location info which it can recognise. However when the software is installed in the mobile device (HTC desire-Z), it gets installed directly in the SD card. This disables this feature as it has no access to the sms folder of the phone.

On a windows mobile phone it is possible to install the software on the main memory and the maps on the SD card and it works that way.

Is something similar possible to do on the android phone? OR is it a matter of the destinator developers to alter the way the software gets installed?

Can the android sms folder be linked to the destinator software somehow?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a different approach - in Android you can subscribe to the event for when an SMS is received. This way your application will receive a notification when a message is received by the phone, after which you can basicly do whatever you need to so with the received message. No need to manually access anything like an SMS folder.

Take a peek at the 'receive' SMS Part of http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: this doesnt help me much who i know little about software manipulation. All i need is for the destinator software to be able to associate the folder: messages from the SD card which is installed, to the folder that all sms are installed in the android phone. That way destinator knows which messages are to be used as location data.